# Reading parquet file with PySpark

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I am new to Pyspark and nothing seems to be working out. Please rescue.
I want to read a parquet file with Pyspark. I wrote the following codes.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.read.parquet("my_file.parquet")
```

I got the following error

> Py4JJavaError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>
> /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       320             else:

then I tried the following codes

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

SQLContext.read.parquet("my_file.parquet")
```

Then the error was as follows :

> AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'parquet'

Comment: try this : `SQLContext.read.format("parquet").load("my_file.parquet")`. same error ?

Comment: @ Steven ... tried but same error. I think the error is in creation of sql context.

Comment: @deega Could you upload this parquet file somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance of SQLContext first.

This will work from pyspark shell:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.read.parquet("my_file.parquet")
```

If you are using spark-submit you need to create the SparkContext in which case you would do this:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.read.parquet("my_file.parquet")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc.stop()
conf = (conf.setMaster('local[*]'))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.parquet("my_file.parquet")
```

Try this.